# MFC CMFCVisualManager Override

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to override some functions on CMFCVisualManager to customize my ribbon. So I created a class and derived from it.

```
void CMyVisualManager::OnDrawRibbonCategory(CDC* pDC, CMFCRibbonCategory* pCategory, CRect rectCategory)
```

Now this works and can change colors etc, but there are some functions that I cant or override or not doing it right like

```
void CMyVisualManager::OnDrawRibbonLaunchButton(CDC* pDC, CMFCRibbonLaunchButton* pButton, CMFCRibbonPanel* pPanel)
```

My method doesnt override the original, and the original function gets called

But https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/65a24718-8128-43f9-973d-25262bdceae7(v=vs.90)
says it can be overridden.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I've been looking but can't find an answer thanks

Comment: _"but there are some functions that I cant or override"_ - What does this mean?  Are you getting an error message?  More details please.

Comment: No my overridden function doesn't get called but the original instead no errors

Answer (score 0):

Yes you override a function in your class.

But you visual manager isn't the one that is created. So it is never used. 
When your program starts an instance of the visual manager is created. And this instance is used.

Only if you also force the MFC to use your visual manager your overriden functions are used.

There for use [SetDefaultManager](http://CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager) with the runtime class of your class in InitInstance of your program.