# Derive a custom class from CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I was trying to derive a custom class from CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007. Can you suggest me steps to be followed in order to derive a CCustomMFCVisualManagerOffice2007?

I am getting following error:

> error C2248:
>   'CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007': cannot
>   access protected member declared in class
>   'CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007'

I am looking for something on the lines of:
[MFC CMFCVisualManager Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790528/mfc-cmfcvisualmanager-override/42635050?noredirect=1#comment72397721_42635050)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Without further information, I am suspecting the `CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007` constructor is private. What is the Visual c++ version you are using?